# Select with simplification does not work

Tags: simplifying-expressions, filtering, conditional

Given a list, I want to find all elements that have positive imaginary part.

For example, if $y,z\in\mathbb R$ and $a>0$ and the list is $\{ ia+y, -ia+z\}$, then the result should be $\{ia+y\}$.

However, my code using `Assuming` and `Select` does not work.

```
Assuming[{y \[Element] Reals, z \[Element] Reals, a > 0}, 
 Select[{I a + y, -I a + z2}, Im[#] > 0 &]]
```

Although the expected reslut is `{I a + y}`, Mathematica gives `{}`. I suspect that condition given by `Assuming` seems to be not effective. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `Assuming[{y \[Element] Reals, z2 \[Element] Reals, a > 0}, Select[{I a + y, -I a + z2}, Simplify[Im[#] > 0] &]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Refine` to evaluate `a > 0`

```
Assuming[{a > 0}, a > 0]
(*a>0*)

Assuming[{a > 0}, Refine[a > 0]]
(*True*)
```

So you can

```
Assuming[{y ∈ Reals, z ∈ Reals, a > 0}, Select[{I a + y, -I a + z2}, Refine[Im[#] > 0] &]]

(*{I a + y}*)
```